# A question about ``frequency of p-values''

Tags: p-value, random-generation

In [NIST 800-22](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf), a battery of tests for rejecting a random number generator, they present their results with 10 columns expressing the frequency of p-values  (section 5.7, interpretation of results, page 101).

Here's an example:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9 C10  P-VALUE  PROPORTION  STATISTICAL TEST
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0   1   1   1   0   0   0   2   3   2  0.350485     10/10      Frequency
```

The test frequency checks that a sample of the bits shows a uniform distribution of zeros and ones.

This test used 10 samples.  Apparently each p-value obtained from each sample fell in a particular column.  The document says they used ``ten discrete bins'' (footnote 10).

What do these bins correspond to?  In other words, what do these columns C1, C2, ..., C10 mean?

Comment: The footnote says, "The unit interval has been divided into ten discrete bins". That sounds to me like they divided it into $[0, 0.1)$, $[0.1, 0.2)$, $[0.2, 0.3)$, etc. But the wording is vague and this question might not have a "correct" answer (unless one of the study authors sees this and responds).

Comment: @shadowtalker You are correct, as one can ascertain by reproducing the values in the "P-VALUE" column.  That's definitive evidence.  Note that these "p-values" are not accurate p-values in cases like the example, which has only 10 observations: the total number of observations needs to be around 50 or larger.

Comment: Looks like @shadowtalker got it.  That does seem to be the answer.  Thanks!